# How to define a unique index in Prisma where one of the constraints is an enum value

Tags: mysql, prisma

Using Prisma's unique indexes: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#defining-a-unique-field

Is it possible to do something like the following (pseudo):

```
model Foo {
  id               String           @id @default(uuid())
  name             String
  userId           String
  createdAt        DateTime         @default(now())
  updatedAt        DateTime         @updatedAt
  type             FooType
  @@unique([userId, FooType.bar])
}

enum FooType {
  bar
  baz
}
```

The resulting constraint would state, "there cannot be more than 1 row with a userId of `X` and a `FooType` of `bar` (more than 1 `baz` is fine)"